# Simplifying a conditional expectation using LIE

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is it possible to simplify the following expression, using LIE or otherwise?

$\mathbb{E}\left[(1-X)\mathbb{E}(Y|X)+X\mathbb{E}(Z|X)\right]$

where $X, Y \text{and } Z$ are random variables with $X, Y$ and $X, Z$ correlated. At a glance, it looks like it could work down to something like

$\mathbb{E}(1-X)\mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Z)$

or

$\mathbb{E}[(1-X)Y+XZ]$

but neither seems possible. If all these expressions are different, what would be an intuitive way of understanding the difference between them all?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[(1-X)Y+XZ]$ looks reasonable while $\mathbb{E}(1-X)\mathbb{E}(Y)+\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Z)$ may not be in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pushing $1-X$ and $X$ into the inner expectations (check that you understand why this is possible), we have
$$E[E[(1-X)Y \mid X] + E[XZ \mid X]] = E[(1-X)Y] + E[XZ] = E[(1-X)Y + XZ].$$

If $E[Y\mid X] = E[Y]$ and $E[Z \mid X] = E[Z]$ (e.g., if $Y$ and $Z$ are each independent of $X$), then you could rewrite your original expression as $E[1-X] E[Y] + E[X] E[Z]$. But this does not hold in general.

Comment: Ah of course! I'm quite rusty on probability... but since $X$ is conditioned on in both expectations, that would allow us to move $1-X$ and $$ into both. Thank you!